# PHP PDO ODBC connection

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, qlikview

we are trying to create a connection with our SQL database trough ODBC in PHP.

This is our current script:

```
$cnx = new PDO("odbc:Driver={EFR};Server=localhost;Port:7004;Database=EFR;Uid=LcLfVJFLTKTCEHRO;Pwd=*********;");
```

The driver is working in Qlikview which also connects to this database.

The driver is actually being found by PHP, but we think it just can't login.

PHP is returning the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IM001] SQLDriverConnect: 0 No transaction control system' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\index.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\index.php(2): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver={EF...')
#1 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\index.php on line 2
```

We hope someone can help us out with this problem.

Comment: Try this as your connection string: `$cnx = new PDO("odbc:Driver={EFR};Server=localhost;Port:7004;Database=EFR", 'LcLfVJFLTKTCEHRO', '*********');`

Answer (score 8):

if you already have the ODBC defined and have a stored password, you can simply connect with

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:DSN_NAME")
```

where DSN_NAME is the actual name of your ODBC datasource, be it MySQL, SQL Server or DB2.

You can test your connection with the following:

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO ("odbc:DSN_NAME");

    die(json_encode(array('outcome' => true)));
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
     die(json_encode(array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect')));
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is DNS_NAME, can be the IP number?

Comment: Using the string "odbc:DNS_NAME" the result is `{"outcome":false,"message":"Unable to connect"}`

Answer (score 1):

try adding DSN on System instead of user

Answer (score 0):

Possibly extension folder is located in the wrong place

open php.ini file and check "extension_dir"